# Ext JS custom Tooltip class not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, extjs, tooltip

I went of Ext's QuickTips to make this custom tooltip, that should show a tooltip when over an element with a 'my_tip' attribute.

For example,

```
<div class="some class" my_tip="This is my tip text">
```

When the page is loaded, it adds the following markup to the HTML, which is correct:

```
<div class="x-layer my_tool_tip_layer" id="ext-gen7" style="position: absolute; z-index: 20000; visibility: hidden; left: -10000px; top: -10000px;">
    <div class="my_tool_tip" id="ext-gen8">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

What should happen is when I hover the mouse over the element with the 'my_tip' attribute, it should update the above div's style attribute and replace &nbsp with the contents of the my_tip class.

Like this:

```
<div class="x-layer my_tool_tip_layer displayed" id="ext-gen7" style="position: absolute; z-index: 20000; visibility: visible; left: 160px; top: 30px;">
    <div class="my_tool_tip" id="ext-gen8">This is my tip text</div>
</div>
```

I have a css file handling the styling of the tooltip, but my problem now is just getting the html to update to the correct events, which it is not doing.

Below is the javascript for the tooltip. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thank you

```
myToolTips=function()
{
    var mytt_ext_lyr=null;
    var mytt_text_el=null;
    var mytt_visible=false;
    var mytt_hide_proc=null;
    var mytt_show_proc=null;
    var mytt_tip_text='';
    var mytt_hide_delay = 10000;
    var mytt_show_delay = 200;
    var mytt_started = false;
    var mytt_last_xy = null;
    var mytt_mouse_y_offset = 20;
    var mytt_track_mouse = false;
    var mytt_initialized = false;
    var mytt_singleton = null;
    var mytt_max_search_depth = 5;

    var on_over = function(evt) {
        var target = evt.target;
        var depth = 0;

        while (target && target.nodeType == 1 && !target.getAttribute('my_tip') && depth < mytt_max_search_depth) {
            ++depth;
            target = target.parentNode;
        }

        if (!target || target.nodeType != 1 || !target.getAttribute('my_tip')) {
            if (mytt_visible)
                hide();
            return;
        }

        var new_tip = target.getAttribute('my_tip');
        if (new_tip != mytt_tip_text && mytt_visible)
            hide();
        if (target.getAttribute('clip_tip') && target.getAttribute('clip_tip') == 'true') {
            for (var i = 0; i < target.childNodes.length; ++i) {
                var child = target.childNodes[i];
                if (child.scrollWidth <= child.offsetWidth) {
                    return;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (target.getAttribute('clip_tip') && target.getAttribute('clip_tip') == 'this_node') {
            if (target.scrollWidth <= target.offsetWidth)
                return;
        }
        var mouse_xy = evt.getXY();
        var tip = {mouse_xy: mouse_xy, new_tip: new_tip, target: target}
        mytt_show_proc = show.defer(mytt_show_delay, mytt_singleton, [tip]);
        mytt_started = true;
    };

    var on_move = function (evt) {
        if (mytt_visible) {
            if (mytt_track_mouse) {
                var mouse_xy = evt.getXY();
                mouse_xy[1] += mytt_mouse_y_offset;
                mytt_ext_lyr.setXY(mouse_xy);
            }
        }
        else if (mytt_started)
            mytt_last_xy = evt.getXY();
    };

    var on_out=function(evt) {
        hide();
    };

    var on_click = function(evt) {
        var target = evt.target;
        var depth = 0;
        while (target && target.nodeType == 1 && !target.getAttribute('my_tip') && depth < mytt_max_search_depth) {
            ++depth;
            target = target.parentNode;
        }
        if (!target || target.nodeType != 1 || !target.getAttribute('my_tip'))
            hide();
    };

    var show=function(mytt) {
        var tip=mytt.new_tip;
        var mouse_xy=mytt.mouse_xy;
        if(mytt_last_xy)
            mouse_xy=mytt_last_xy;
        if(!mytt_visible) {
            if(tip) {
                mytt_tip_text=tip;
                mytt_text_el.update(mytt_tip_text.replace(/\[\[/g,"<").replace(/\]\]/g,">"));
            }
            mytt_ext_lyr.show();
            mytt_ext_lyr.addClass('displayed');
            mytt_visible=true;
            if(!mytt_hide_proc)
                mytt_hide_proc=setTimeout(hide,mytt_hide_delay);
        }
        var db=Ext.get(document.body);
        var dw=db.getWidth();
        var dh=db.getHeight();
        if (mytt.target.getAttribute('top_tip') === 'true') {
            var telm = Ext.get(mytt.target);
            var left = telm.getLeft();
            var width_diff = db.getWidth() - (left + mytt_ext_lyr.getWidth());
            if (width_diff < 5)
                left+=width_diff-15;
            mytt_ext_lyr.dom.style.right='';
            mytt_ext_lyr.dom.style.top='';
            mytt_ext_lyr.dom.style.left=left+'px';
            mytt_ext_lyr.dom.style.bottom=(dh-telm.getTop())+'px';
            mytt_ext_lyr.sync();
        }
        else {
            mouse_xy[1]+=mytt_mouse_y_offset;
            var width_diff=db.getWidth()-(mouse_xy[0]+mytt_ext_lyr.getWidth());
            if(width_diff<5)
                mouse_xy[0]+=width_diff-15;
            mytt_ext_lyr.setXY(mouse_xy);
        }
        if(mytt_show_proc) {
            clearTimeout(mytt_show_proc);
            mytt_show_proc=null;
        }
    };

    var hide=function() {
        mytt_ext_lyr.hide();
        mytt_ext_lyr.removeClass('displayed');
        mytt_visible=false;
        mytt_started=false;
        mytt_last_xy=null;
        if(mytt_hide_proc) {
            clearTimeout(mytt_hide_proc);
            mytt_hide_proc=null;
        }
        if(mytt_show_proc) {
            clearTimeout(mytt_show_proc);
            mytt_show_proc=null;
        }
    };

    return {
        init:function() {
            mytt_singleton=myToolTips;
            if(!mytt_initialized) {
                if(!Ext.isReady) {
                    Ext.onReady(myToolTips.init,myToolTips);
                    return;
                }
                mytt_ext_lyr=new Ext.Layer({cls:'my_tool_tip_layer',shim:true,constrain:true});
                mytt_ext_lyr.fxDefaults={stopFx:true};
                mytt_ext_lyr.update('<div class="my_tool_tip">&nbsp;</div>');
                mytt_text_el=mytt_ext_lyr.child('div.my_tool_tip');
                mytt_text_el.update('&nbsp;');
                var doc=Ext.get(document);
                doc.on('mouseover',on_over);
                doc.on('mouseout',on_out);
                doc.on('mousemove',on_move);
                doc.on('click',on_click);
                mytt_initialized=true;
            }
        },

        ready:function() {
            return mytt_initialized;
        }
    };
}();


// make tooltips work
myToolTips.init();
```

Comment: Do you need this special behavior for a 3rd party library?

Comment: Have a look at http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.tip.QuickTip and  http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.tip.ToolTip I'm pretty certain you can get most of the functionality you're after in much less code when implementing those components.

Comment: @Saki This is just for a custom tooltip used on the entire web application, initialized on load. Not used anywhere else for now. Another javascript file handles the creation of the elements with the my_tip attribute. But thats it. Just not sure why it doesnt do anything (not updating the HTMLElement). Thanks

Comment: @RobSchmuecker I've gone through the api. I'm actually using Ext Js 1.1.1 (I have to work on this version for now). But my question is not so much regarding how to do it differently, as to understanding why its not working at all. Thanks

Comment: Do you have a demo anywhere or can you perhaps make a jsfiddle.net or a fiddle.sencha.com?

Comment: @RobSchmuecker Here as a quick jsfiddle as an example. https://jsfiddle.net/lmoreira2012/gbf2m1L1/

Comment: @Luiz well, it looks like `removeClass` and `show.defer` aren't valid defined functions.  `removeCls` is a valid function but I'm not too sure what `show` is meant to be? You said you're using ExtJS 1.1.1?! This example uses 4.1.1 and you must load it without HTTPS as otherwise the ExtJS won't load.  Try this link therefore http://jsfiddle.net/lmoreira2012/gbf2m1L1/ and use a javascript debugger!

Comment: @RobSchmuecker Thank you. I know The example is with 4.1.1 It would be nice to be able to have 1.1.1 in jsfiddle to test. Is there something for that? Because removeClass exists in that version. As for the `show.defer` it is from the function `var show = function (mytt) {` in my code.